# Why my bot isn't pinging the user when mentioned in v13?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm sending a message and it shows up in the channel, but I don't get the red ping notification even though I'm being mentioned. This is my code

```js
await message.guild["channels"].cache
  .get(<SOME_ID>)
  .send({
    allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true },
    content: `Welcome <@${message.author.id}> this is your channel`
  });
```

Why wouldn't I get notified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to add `allowedMentions: { users: [message.author.id]}`

The final code would be:

```js
await message.guild["channels"].cache
  .get(<SOME_ID>)
  .send({
    allowedMentions: { users: [message.author.id], repliedUser: true },
    content: `Welcome <@${message.author.id}> this is your channel`
  });
```

This pings the given user.